# Is there any interactive shell for module development in cmake?

Tags: cmake

CMake is awesome, especially with lots of modules (FindOOXX). However, when it comes to write a `FindXXX` module, a library XXX which your project depends, it's not that easy to handle for non-cmake-expert. I sometimes encounter a library without support to CMake, and I like to make one for it. I'm wondering if there is any interactive shell while writing/testing cmake modules?

Answer (score 1):

Are you writing `FindXXX` for project "XXX" or is "XXX" a dependency of your project that you're trying to find? If the former, you should instead write a file called `XXX-config.cmake` (or `XXXConfig.cmake`) and install it into one of the directories mentioned in the docs for `find_package`. In general, `XXX-config.cmake` files are for projects which are expected to be found by CMake (and installed by the project itself) and `FindXXX.cmake` files are for projects which don't support CMake (and usually have to support finding any version of XXX).

That said, for `FindXXX.cmake`, usually you just need a few `find_file` (e.g., for headers), some `find_library` calls, or even just a single `pkg_check_module` from `FindPkgConfig.cmake` followed by a `find_package_handle_standard_args` call (use `include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)` to get it). FPHSA makes writing proper Find modules a breeze.

For `XXX-config.cmake` files, I have typically used `configure_file` to generate two versions: one for the install (which includes your `install(EXPORT)` file) and one for the build tree (generated by `export()` calls). Using this, other useful variables can be accurately set such as things like "which exact version of Boost was used" or "was Python support compiled in" so that dependent projects can get a better picture of what the dependency looks like.

I have also recently discovered that CMake ships with the `CMakePackageConfigHelpers` module which is supposed to help with making these files. There looks to be quite a bit of documentation for it.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive response. I'm looking for writing a `FindXXX` for a project which doesn't support CMake. I should make my question clearer.